# How to preselect/check a default radio button in yii2 RadioList()?

Tags: php, html, yii2, active-form

I want the radio button preselected in my form.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'config')->radioList(['1'=>'Automatic Entry',2=>'Manual Entry'])
     ->label('Barcode/Book No Generation'); ?>
```

Comment: You're talking about this? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#radioList()-detail If so, that seem to have $options where you can set the default selection.

Comment: i already gone through this doc, if anyone find the attribute name, then i want a demo?

Comment: In my test the radio button is normally preselected (ther first one) just a minor the 2 is better if you code `'2'` like the first.

Comment: The default radio button (pre selected) is normally the first radio button. In my test ithe firts is always already cheked. And second point  in your code the value 2 is not with quotes. I hope thi is more clear ..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The preselected values are taken from `$model->config`.  That means that you should set that attribute to the value that you want preselected :

```
$model->config = '1';
$form->field($model, 'config')->radioList([
    '1' => 'Automatic Entry',
    '2' => 'Manual Entry',
]);
```

The relevant doc for this is in the [ActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#radioList()-detail) class.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use default value of radio, you can use following codes:

```
<?php $model->isNewRecord==1 ? $model->config=1:$model->config;?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'config')->radioList(
    [
         '1'=>'Automatic Entry',
         '2'=>'Manual Entry'
    ])->label('Barcode/Book No Generation'); 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set 'config' attribute.

```
$model->config = 1;
```

You'll have first radio button selected when form is loaded.

tarleb is right.

Answer (score -3):

Long shot in the dark since I'm not awfully familiar with yii2, but based on the documentation you should be able to do something like this.

```
$form->field($model, 'config')->radioList([
          '1'=>'Automatic Entry',
          '2'=>'Manual Entry',
    ], [
        'item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
            return Html::radio($name, $checked, ['value' => $value]);
        },
    ]);
// [...]
ActiveForm::end();
```